# how to use CustomTreeCtrl with the TR_HAS_VARIABLE_ROW_HEIGHT style to change the items height?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I gave my CustomTreeCtrl the TR_HAS_VARIABLE_ROW_HEIGHT style. But I am not sure where to go from there to change the height of the items inside the tree.

I cant really find anything on the API or online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you have to do is change the font size of the item.  That's what it looks like in the wxPython demo anyway. You could ask on the wxPython users group though. The author of that widget is on there most of the time and is very helpful.